# Asus n-10 nano wireless adapret not connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04, asus

I'm using asus n-10 nano wireless adapter and I can't connect to the internet with it. I was trying everything. I'm working on ubuntu 15.4. I was searching and trying many things but nothing was successful.

Here is result of lsmod | grep8192:

```
rtl8192se              65536  0 
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192se
rtl8192cu              69632  0 
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  5 rtl_pci,rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu,rtl8192se
mac80211              724992  5 rtl_pci,rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8192se
```

[Here](http://wklej.org/hash/4f97f553c1e/) are info from "Wireless Info Script"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using a USB wireless when you have a working internal device? I suspect the drivers conflict.

Comment: Oh, that's because thas usb don't work under my PC, and i think, that the problem can be the same. But there i don't have any other internat card

Comment: May we see the wireless info script from the computer where the USB wireless will actually be used? The script you posted above is not relevant.

Comment: So how can I shut down internal device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please detach the USB wireless temporarily. We will install a better, more stable driver for the USB:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

Now, let's blacklist the internal device:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192se"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot with the USB inserted and tell us if it is working.

To accomplish this offline, go here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Select Vivid in the drop-down box. Search for linux-headers-generic and build-essential. Be sure to locate their dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies. Be sure to download the correct version, either 32- or 64-bit. Once you've download about fifteen or so packages on another computer, transfer them with a USB stick or similar to the desktop of your Ubuntu computer. Open a terminal and install them:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It may complain that a package is missing a dependency. If so, download that and add it to the desktop and try again.

Write many posts to tell old Chili how you're stuck. Rinse and repeat.

Once that's all done, get this: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/master.zip Download it and then transfer it to your desktop, too. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal.

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.

After you are then connected, I recommend that you then follow the more permanent *dkms* method I described above.

Obviously, if you are able to get, even for a few moments, an alternate internet connection, the process will be immeasurably faster and easier.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! It worked. Now i have to try this on my main computer. Can you tell me how to install that, when I can't connect computer to the internet?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Adding the ppa does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 . Is the answer outdated, or only working for Ubuntu 15 specifically?

Comment: Likely *every* wireless answer from 2015 is now obsolete. Please start your own new question. @user985366